# what is good solution from template pointer: *(T*) to C++ type casting?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, casting

I'd like to convert C style template pointer: *(T*)(&buf[index]) to c++ type casting in bytebuffer code.

code in https://github.com/RamseyK/ByteBufferCpp/blob/master/src/ByteBuffer.hpp#L170

```cpp
template<typename T> 
T read(uint32_t index) const {
    if (index + sizeof(T) <= buf.size())
        return *((T*) &buf[index]); //C Style Cast
    return 0;
}
```

My solution: C++ Type cast

```
return *(reiterpret_cast<T*>(&buf[index])); //C++ Style Cast
```

Is this good solution?

Or other good solutions with c++11?

Comment: This probably causes undefined behaviour due to strict aliasing violation. The code should be `T t = 0; if (size check) memcpy(&t, &buf[index], sizeof t); return t;` or similar

Comment: @M.M unless someone placement `new`'d a T there previously

Comment: Strict aliasing does allow dereferencing following a cast to a pointer to objects of the same size but different sign or const, etc, and always allows casting to char type pointers. If that is acceptable, you could add a static assert or similar that the sizeof T is 1. If you want to cast to a larger object, that is going to be troublesome, as you have no guarantees about the alignment of the underlying byte vector.

Comment: But given that you use sizeof(T) in there I guess you want to use it for larger types. That isn't good, and may not run in practice if the platform is arm, or SSE is used, as they demand alignment of larger integral types.